# From - correct preposition

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

It was my turn to go on stage to perform in the talent competition. I was very anxious and nervous.

After I had taken courage, I started singing my favorite song; it was "Perfect" by Ed Sheeran. In the middle of my performance, I heard a woman shout: "You're spectacular!"

While I was on my way back to the dressing room, the other contestants congratulated me on my voice. Once I got to the dressing room, I rested for a while. Then, suddenly, someone knocked on the door and when they opened it, they said: "I've finally found you!"

It was the woman **from** the audience. We spent the rest of the day talking and became good friends.

Comment: There is no question here. What is your question?

Comment: Hi randomhead, sorry, I thought my question was understandable from the title. My question is: is the highlighted "from" the correct preposition to use in that sentence? Thanks!

Comment: Asking "is this word correct?" is off-topic here—it is considered a request for proofreading. We need to know why you are asking the question: do *you* think the word is correct? Why, or why not? What research have you done, and why are you still unsure after doing that research? Answering those questions will make your question more on-topic for the site and will help us answer you better.